# Is this curve a cycloid? How to prove or disprove this preposition?

Tags: calculus, functions, curves, cycloid

I have this complicated function given by:

$$y(x)=c-\sqrt{(g^2-4\omega^4x^2)}-g\log(\sqrt{(g^2-4\omega^4x^2)}+g$$

This looks sort of like a cycloid for different values of the constants $\omega,g$ and $c.$

You check out it's shape on desmos (online graphing tool): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gtpkp9agxl

My question is, of course, is it a cycloid?

Comment: I'd say with 99.9% confidence that no, of course it's not. Look at the usual parametric equations for a cycloid. How does $1-\cos t$ turn into a function of $t-\sin t$ involving $\log$?

Comment: The graph looks like some sort of parabola and not a cycloid

Comment: Play around with the constants and you'll see what I am talking about.